# Install app for only some users in a domain

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-for-education

Is there a way to limit the installation of Google Marketplace Apps to only certain users besides the built-in "organizations" setup?  I want to allow my customers to install my app for a set of users, but their users are already in different sub-organizations and the customer doesn't want to rearrange all that just for my app.

There's no clear easy way to do this, but maybe there's a complex one like going through the users one-by-one and installing the app for each one?  Can the administrator grant me access to do that for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [developer docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/175747?hl=en):

> *Can I control all settings based on a user's organizational unit?*
>
> At this time, you can only control which Google Apps services are
>   available. All other settings apply to all users, regardless of which
>   organizational unit they belong to. Google recognizes the need to
>   control other settings, such as the ability to chat outside of your
>   organization, but this level of granularity is not yet available.

So not yet but it sounds like they recognize the need for 3rd party developers to have the same control over their apps as Google.